# Is a Backbone.js collection sorted?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it like a "list", where order matters?

Or is it not sorted at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, no they're not sorted. But they will be sorted if you provide a comparator function: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator

Answer (score 1):

By default it is "ordered" (insertion order) but not "sorted".